# Linux command to remove the duplicate lines but keep the first occurrence

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, string-manipulation

I have a text file. Each line contains a string. Some strings are repeated. I want to remove repetition but I want to keep the first occurrence. For example:

```
line1
line1
line2
line3
line4
line3
line5
```

Should be

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

I tried: `sort file1 | uniq -u > file2` but this did not help. It removed all repeated strings while I want the first occurrence to be present. I do not need to sort. Just remove the exact repetition of a string in a new line while keeping everything else as it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you allow sorting anyway, this will work:

```
sort | uniq
```

`-u` was the source of your trouble, because (from [`man 1 uniq`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uniq.1.html)):

> `-u`, `--unique`
>   only print unique lines

while by default:

> With no options, matching lines are merged to the first occurrence.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to dedup while keeping first occurrence, you can do

```
awk '!visited[$0]++' "$your_hist_file" > "$your_new_hist_file"
```

If you want to dedup while keeping last occurrence, you can do

```
tac "$your_hist_file" | awk '!visited[$0]++' | tac > "$your_new_hist_file"
```

You can use one `awk` command and no `tac` to achieve this too, but it's as straightforward as using two `tac`s.

Answer (score 0):

Specialized utils that print unique lines *without* sorting:

1. [`uq`](https://github.com/lostutils/uq).
2. [`unique`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/unique.8.html).

See also: [How to get only the unique results without having to sort data?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11939/how-to-get-only-the-unique-results-without-having-to-sort-data) and [Unix: removing duplicate lines without sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532157/unix-removing-duplicate-lines-without-sorting).

Answer (score 0):

```
sort file1 |
awk '{
if (!visited[$1])
{
  print $0;
  visited[$1]=1;
} else {
 print "print this only to check that skip not desired lines $0;"
}
}'
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.